# Rails Gemfile: use one line in development, another in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

We run Unicorn on Heroku in production but use Webrick in development on a local machine. We are unable to install Unicorn on the local machine.

Is it possible to have Rails load the Unicorn gem only in production? Right now, our solution is to comment out the Unicorn gem when running the app locally and uncomment the gem when pushing to Heroku.

We're on Rails 3.2.12.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'jquery-rails'


# # =========================================================================================
# 
# #=========================================================================================
gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'plucky'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'bson'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rpm_contrib'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: As long as your Gemfile looks right and you have bundled right, Unicorn should be available locally as well. Can you check if Unicorn is under any group in the Gemfile?

Comment: @membLoper, updated with our Gemfile

Comment: The reason we can't use Unicorn is because our dev machine is a Windows machine right now, and Unicorn doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have Rails load the Unicorn gem only in production?
>   Right now, our solution is to comment out the Unicorn gem when running
>   the app locally and uncomment the gem when pushing to Heroku.

Yes, it is possible by the use of groups in `Gemfile`.  Update your `Gemfile` like follows for the `unicorn` gem in `production` only:

```
# Gemfile
group :production do 
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

Since `WEBrick` is the default web server for rails apps, you wouldn't need to specify anything for `development` group.

Running `bundle install` after the `Gemfile` update will still install the production gems.  This is definitely a good thing to do as you want to make sure the gems you are planning to use in production work correctly with your application from the development phase of project.

To skip installation of `production` group gems:

```
bundle install --without production
```

A point to be noted about the `--without production` option is that the subsequent calls to `bundle install` and `bundle update` are also going to skip installing and updating production gems.  To disable this you'd need to remove the line`BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production` from your `app_root/.bundle/config`:

```
# app_root/.bundle/config

BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

Comment: hmm, the group didn't seem to work. when we run "rails s" in development, it's displaying an error about not finding the unicorn gem. anything else?

Comment: Search for reference to unicorn in your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.  You might also need to do `bundle clean --force` then `bundle install --without production`.  Give these a try, they might help!

Comment: still doesn't work. does this work for rails 3.2.12?

Comment: @Crashalot, sorry for the late reply.  Wanted to let you know that this is tested in `Rails 3.2.16`.